# Does anyone know why this compiles successfully?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

```
int main()
{
   // forward declaration
   struct myStruct_st *mS; // Note that this will expand as "struct struct myStruct_st *mS which does not make any sense to me"

   return 0;
}

// definition of myStruct_s
typedef struct myStruct_s
{
   int x;
   int y;
} myStruct_st;
```

I understand that myStruct_s is the structure that needs to be forward declared. I had this typo in my code which seemed to compile. I wonder how though. Does anyone know?

Comment: This is just a side comment, but I generally put `typedef`s and such _before_ `main()` (when I don't include them in a header file instead, that is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local struct has *nothing to do* with the struct defined outside of `main()`. In `main()` you (forward-)declare a struct, define a pointer to that struct and never define the struct. That's perfectly OK. It so happens that you define a struct with the same name outside `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how the `typedef` works -- it is not macro substitution.

In particular, using  `struct myStruct_s` after the `typedef` is *not* the same as "`struct struct myStruct_s`" -- it's simply `struct myStruct_s`, as it reads on the face.  The typedef introduces a token which can be used rather than `struct ...`, but it doesn't expand like a macro and it doesn't "wipe out" the `struct ...` declaration, which can still be used.

Comment: I understand that. My question is how does struct myStruct_st *mS work? Note that myStruct_st is a typedef for struct myStruct_s. I believe Armen has answered that.